# Jquery Mobile Menu - Off The Page

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu, slide

So I am coding a website at the moment and am using a mobile menu that slides in from the right hand side and it works perfectly when viewed through a laptop browser. The way I am doing it is to absolute position the menu 200px off the screen and then slide it in using JQuery by animating the -200px right to 0px.

```
<script>
$('#mobileIcon').click(function(){
    $('#mobileNavigation').animate({right:'0'}, 1000);
});
$('#mobileNavigation li.first span').click(function(){
    $('#mobileNavigation').animate({right:'-200'}, 1000);
});
</script>
```

The problem comes when viewing the site on my Iphone in that the menu is shown to the right if you scroll across to it and this shouldn't be the case!

If you view the site on your browser and reduce the width to mobile size and then try scrolling to the right you will see nothing but if you view it on a mobile and swipe to the right you will see what I mean:

http://dev.evaske.com/EvaskeResponsive/

Why is it doing this only on a mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using a fixed position instead of absolute positioning.